# Equivalent to first./last. SAS processing in R

Tags: r

I did find a thread on this ([R equivalent of .first or .last sas operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765834/r-equivalent-of-first-or-last-sas-operator)) but it did not fully answer my question.

I come from a SAS background and a common operation is, for example, when you have your patient ID with several different values, and you want to keep only the row with the minimum/maximum value for another variable for each ID. For example, I might have data with dates of a certain medical problem for each ID, and I want a dataset with just the first/last problem date for each patient.

Here's a simple example that gets me what I'm want, but I want to know if there's a better way to do it. I sort by ID, and then count, and I want to just keep the row with the largest count for each ID.

```
testdata<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,4),
                 count=c(5,9,2,6,16,12,0,11,8,8,7))

library(dplyr)

testdata2<-arrange(testdata,id,count)

testdata3<-cbind(testdata2,!duplicated(testdata2$id,fromLast=TRUE))

testdata4<-subset(testdata3,testdata3[,3]=='TRUE')[,-3]


> testdata4
    id count
3   1     9
4   2     6
7   3    16
11  4     8
```

Is there a more compact way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply aggregate: `rbind(aggregate(count~id, testdata, min), aggregate(count~id, testdata, max))`

Comment: wow that's really good, and doesn't even require the data to be sorted. thanks!

Comment: looks like if I have a larger dataset and want to keep the other variables that were not used for the sorting, the way to go is to put that into a data frame, then do an inner join with the original data

Comment: Indeed. You can even use `ave` for inline aggregation: `testdata$min <- ave(testdata$count, testdata$id, FUN=min); testdata$max <- ave(testdata$count, testdata$id, FUN=max)`. Then, subset by these new columns: `subset(testdata, count == min | count == max)`.

Comment: You shouldn't add a "SOLUTION" to your question. You should either accept an answer below, or if none of the answers fully meets your needs, add your own answer below. This allows the community to vote on what they believe the "right" answer is.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm pretty new here. I just marked Parfait's solution as useful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame,
        c(by(testdata, testdata$id, function(d) d[c(1L,nrow(d)),]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#       id count
# 1.1    1     5
# 1.3    1     2
# 2.4    2     6
# 2.4.1  2     6
# 3.5    3    16
# 3.8    3    11
# 4.7    4     0
# 4.11   4     7
```

Breaking it down:

- `d[c(1L,nrow(d)),]` returns the first and last row from the dataframe. (I'm assuming the frame has already been ordered appropriately.)
- `by(testdata, testdata$id, function` breaks the larger frame into smaller frames by `$id`, and passes each smaller frame to the anonymous function. This returns a `by`-list of each return value.
- `do.call(rbind.data.frame,` grabs the list and row-binds them back together into a single frame. Since the default is to use `factor`s, I added `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

If you want to use `dplyr`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(testdata, id) %>%
  slice(c(1,n())) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 × 2
#      id count
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     5
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     6
# 4     2     6
# 5     3    16
# 6     3    11
# 7     4     0
# 8     4     7
```

where `n()` is a special function within `dplyr` pipes that returns the number of rows in that (optionally-grouped) frame.

Comment: thanks, but I just want to see if there's a faster way to get "testdata4" (which I edited just now to exclude the TRUE/FALSE column). See the end of my post.

Comment: ID=1 has a max of 9.

Comment: Perhaps you'll forgive me misunderstanding your statement *"row with the minimum/maximum value"* as meaning you wanted the row with the minimum value and the row with the maximum value, per id. The comments in the OP seem to fit your needs, though, so I'm leaving this as-is.